# Spring MVC - how to add item to cart?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm writing an application which is very basic Online Shop. I got phones category here (2 phones available), and after click one of them new page with info about phone displays, under description I got button "add to cart", and here is a thing - I want that after click the button all informations about that phone will go to database and display them at the same time in page "cart". Connection to db and managing data in IDE isn't problematic for me, but how "Add to Cart" button will know which phone I chose (phone1 or phone2)? I should create another Controller for Cart or here is another solution for that?

PhoneController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class PhoneController {
DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
Cart cart;

@RequestMapping(value="/phone1.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView phone1Page() {

    ModelAndView phone1 = new ModelAndView("Phone1");

    return phone1; 

}

@RequestMapping(value="/phone2.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView phone2Page() {

    ModelAndView phone2 = new ModelAndView("Phone2");

    return phone2; 

}


@RequestMapping(value="/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addToChart(){


    ModelAndView cart = new ModelAndView("Cart");
    return cart;    

}
}
```

Phone1.jsp:

```
<form action="/OnlineShop/cart.html" method="post">
<div style="padding-right: 40px">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>iPhone 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>400$</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Cart.jsp:

```
<div style="padding-right: 40px">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Product</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>OnlineShop</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.damian.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Comment: You can post your web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `POST` request to your `/cart.html` mapping with a request parameter for example: `/cart.html?selected=iPhone6`. Alternatively you could add form data to your post request with the information about the selected phone. I assume you have the phones also in a database with some sort of identifier, if you hide this identifier in your form then you could easily see which device was selected.

This is one way of solving the problem.

```
<form action="/OnlineShop/cart.html?selectedPhone=iPhone6" method="post">
    <div style="padding-right: 40px">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>iPhone 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Company</td>
                <td>Apple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>Phone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>400$</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
         <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And check the request parameter in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addToChart(@RequestParam String selectedPhone){

    ModelAndView cart = new ModelAndView(selectedPhone);
    return cart;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all informations about the phone will go to database and display them at the same time in page `cart` you can try to add `commandName`  like this:
But before you should create a `dto` class for ex: named `PhoneClass`

```
 class public PhoneClass{
  private name ...;
  private ...
  // and 
  setters and getters
  }

 <form action="/OnlineShop/cart.html" method="post" commandName="phoneInfo">
 <div style="padding-right: 40px">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>iPhone 6</td>
    </tr>
   ...
  <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/>
 </div>
 </form>
```

And in your controller you can do like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someAction(@ModelAttribute("phoneInfo") PhoneClass phoneInfo, Model model) {
    // TODO save un database attributes of `PhoneClass`
    model.addAttribute("phoneInfo", phoneInfo);

    return "somepage";
    }
```

And in your page `Cart.jsp`you can use foreach of `jstl` to retrieve data from atrribute `phoneInfo` and put them in `Cart.jsp` like ths:

```
  <div style="padding-right: 40px">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
   <c:forEach var="element" items="${phoneInfo}" varStatus="status">
    <td> Name</td> <td>${status.name}</td>
        ....
      </c:forEach>

  </div>
```